# Merging duplicate rows instead of removing arbitrarily

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, ssdt-bi

I'm working on an SSIS package where I need to dedupe a list of names, sorted by last name and then first name. There's additional columns such as prefix, middle name, and suffix. The problem I'm encountering is that in some situations I have dupes like:

```
+========+===========+============+==========+========+
| Prefix | FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | Suffix |
+========+===========+============+==========+========+
|        | John      |            | Doe      |        |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
| Mr.    | John      |            | Doe      |        | 
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
|        | John      | A.         | Doe      |        | 
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+--------+
```

If I just let sort remove the dupes it's luck of the draw in terms of which row will survive. But, obviously, I would prefer to preserve as much information as possible.

The best result would obviously be to merge these three so in my result set, I end up with just "Mr. John A. Doe". Short of that, if there's some way I can simply just specify a precedence, like if middle name has a value, then take that one. I might still lose some information, but it's rare in my particular dataset that there's multiple varying dupes like in my example above. Usually, it's just one with a middle name and one without.

For what it's worth I'm working in SSDT-BI in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What about using an Aggregate operation? Group on First and Last, MAX the prefix/middle/suffix

Comment: No, no ID. It's actually a varchar field consisting of multiple names in an old table that I'm breaking up and moving to individual records with a foreign key back to the parent record in a new schema. The qualification for merging is simply if first and last name match. Normally that may not be a good enough condition, but I've gone over the dataset and there's no dupes that aren't truly dupes.

Comment: @billinkc: That's a good suggestion and satisfies my "Plan B" or just taking the one with a middle name if the other(s) don't. I still think merging the records would be the better option if I can achieve it though. If you add your comment as an answer, I can at least give you an upvote and if I can't get my first choice, I'll accept it eventually.

Comment: Help me understand option A then. In the above, you would have 4 rows coming in. Magic happens and the 4 rows go out all with the same name elements?

Comment: Three rows go in, one comes out, but it has all the information that was provided by any of the three rows, i.e. "Mr. (from row 2) John (all rows) A. (from row 3) Doe (all rows)".

Comment: How is that different then from what the Aggregate transformation is going to deliver? Also, is it really just null/empty string vs non-empty string you're concerned about? Are you worried at all about some of the complexity that exists in [name matching](http://superuser.com/questions/480133/record-matching-software-to-compare-two-tables-and-match-on-based/481592#481592)?

Comment: My opinion is that combining two or more (valid) records into a third new variation the programmer generated, might result in an invalid row no-one is accountable for. Better to pick one using a well defined criterion (latest modification date, most non-empty fields, etc). Otherwise your users offered you two records and you serve them back a 3rd alternative! That is of course based on my experience of a BI and you case might differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select max(Prefix), FirstName, max(MiddleName), LastName, max(Suffix) 
  from table 
 group by LastName, FirstName
 order by LastName, FirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you.

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE 
    (EMPLOYEEID INT,
    PREFIX VARCHAR(50) ,
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50) ,
    MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(50) ,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(50) ,
    SUFFIX VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES
    (107,'','JOHN','','DOE',''),
    (107,'MR. ','JOHN','','DOE',''),
    (107,'','JOHN','A.','DOE',''),
    (112,'','JOE','','FRANK',''),
    (112,'','JOEL','','FRANK','')
----------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM @TAB
```

[image]

```
--To bring a Key, I added an EmployeeID.

SELECT  EMPLOYEEID,
        MAX(PREFIX) PREFIX,
        MAX(FIRSTNAME) FIRSTNAME,
        MAX(MIDDLENAME) MIDDLENAME,
        MAX(LASTNAME) LASTNAME,
        MAX(SUFFIX) SUFFIX 
FROM    @TAB
GROUP   BY EMPLOYEEID
```

**result**

[image]